# How can I simplify this module?

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, code-cleanup

I have some method which looks awful(especially number of parameters). I wonder how can I make this code cleaner.

The method works with `JLists` and setting a new model(`DefaultListModel`). So it just swaps items between two `JLists` and deletes swapped item in list where was the item taken.

Сriticism and advice are welcome.

Call the method example:

```
moveToOtherJList(newOrdersModel, newOrdersJList, inProcessOrdersModel, inProcessOrdersJList);
```

The method:

```
private void moveToOtherJList(DefaultListModel firstModel, JList firstJList, DefaultListModel secondModel,  JList secondJList)
{
    int selectedIndex = firstJList.getSelectedIndex();
    secondModel.addElement(firstJList.getSelectedValue());
    secondJList.setModel(secondModel);
    firstModel.remove(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Since you are not setting `firstModel` on `firstJList`, can we assume that it is supposed to be already `firstJList`’s model? Then, why do you need two parameters? And why is setting `secondModel` as `secondJList`’s model part of the method for moving an item? That looks like two entirely unconnected tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have some method which looks awful(especially number of parameters).

Well there is no need to pass either ListModel, since you can get the ListModel from the JList.

So I would define the method as:

```
public void moveToOtherJList(JList fromJList, JList toJList)
{
    int selectedIndex = fromJList.getSelectedIndex();
    DefaultListModel fromModel = (DefaultListModel)fromJList.getModel();
    DefaultListModel toModel = (DefaultListModel)toJList.getModel();

    toModel.addElement(fromJList.getSelectedValue());
    fromModel.remove(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Or just `toModel.addElement(fromModel.remove(selectedIndex));`